# Filtering SQL Results with Tags in a Junction Table

Tags: php, sql, junction-table

I'm trying to select `testID`s based off a set of `tagID`s. I want to select all the tests that are tagged with all of the tags in a set of tags.

For example, if I wanted all the `testID`s tagged with `tagFK 1 and 2`, I would expect to get back only `testID = 7`.
If I wanted `testID`s tagged with `tagFK = 2`, I would expect to get back `testID 7 and 8`.

**test table**

```
+--------+--------+
| testID |  name  |
+--------+--------+
|    6   | string |
+--------+--------+
|    7   | string |
+--------+--------+
|    8   | string |
+--------+--------+
|    9   | string |
+--------+--------+
```

**junc_test_tag table**

```
+--------+-------+
| testFK | tagFK |
+--------+-------+
|    7   |   1   |
+--------+-------+
|    7   |   2   |
+--------+-------+
|    8   |   2   |
+--------+-------+
|    8   |   3   |
+--------+-------+
|    9   |   3   |
+--------+-------+
|    9   |   4   |
+--------+-------+
```

**What I've tried:**

```
SELECT testID 
FROM test
RIGHT JOIN junc_test_tag ON test.testID = junc_test_tag.testFK
WHERE junc_test_tag.tagFK = 1
OR junc_test_tag.tagFK = 2;
```

This query returns duplicates and irrelevant rows. I want the SQL result to be just the relevant rows. In this case, just row 7 from the test table.

How would I structure the query to achieve the outcome I'm looking for?

Comment: whats your expected output? your question is too confusing.

Comment: Your join is wrong. You need `ON test.testID = junc_test_tag.testFK`. I'll flag this question for closing ...

Comment: @printxdiv0 Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question. It was a typo when writing the question, not the actual code. It doesn't actually solve the problem....

Comment: Oh, and you should use a `Inner Join` instead of the Left Join. No offense, just to clarify: Is this your first/one of the first SQL queries you wrote?

Comment: `SELECT Distinct testID 
FROM test
inner JOIN junc_test_tag ON test.testID = junc_test_tag.testFK
WHERE junc_test_tag.tagFK = 1
OR junc_test_tag.tagFK = 2; `. This should get you your results.

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2578a/15, This is what i have tried